# Access Google Classroom API with Service account Credentials

Tags: google-app-engine, service-accounts, google-classroom

I am trying to build a integration with server between our CMS to bridge Google Apps users, classroom users and content management.

I am trying a way to connect and manage classroom assets and operations with server identity. I understand we can do it with caching a admin user credentials, is there a any way to manage it with servers identity?

Comment: What do you mean by "catching an admin user credentials"? have you tried using domain wide delegation? https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: Get offline access and save refresh token of admin. use that token for authenticating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service account to impersonate the domain administrator, assuming you've [delegated authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation). The service account itself can't be an administrator on the domain, but it can impersonate a domain admin, without having to store the admin's credentials.